# asp.net core mvc, make view that all come from string object's html code as a string

Tags: model-view-controller, model, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, jsreport

I want to make a model that takes all the html codes from dynamic string object. Like this:

Model for dynamic html:

```
public class PageHtmlModel
    {
        public string HtmlCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Entity Model

```
public class Entity
    {
        private int _ID;
        private string _Module;
        private string _Explanation;
        private string _Situation;
        private string _Personel;
        private string _PersonelsNotes;
        private string _EndDate;
        public int id { get => _ID; set => _ID = value; }
        public string module { get => _Module; set => _Module = value; }
        public string explanation { get => _Explanation; set => _Explanation = value; }
        public string situation { get => _Situation; set => _Situation = value; }
        public string personel { get => _Personel; set => _Personel = value; }
        public string personels_notes { get => _PersonelsNotes; set => _PersonelsNotes = value; }
        public string end_date { get => _EndDate; set => _EndDate = value; }
    }
```

DataAccesLayer:

```
public static string html()
        {
            PageHtmlModel pageHtmlModel = new PageHtmlModel();
            //Thats All html page comes from string
            pageHtmlModel.HtmlCode = "@model deneme100.Models.Entity <html> <head> <link href='~/css/invoice.css' rel='stylesheet' /> </head> <body> <div class='index-box'> <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'> <tr class='top'> <td colspan='2'> <table> <tr> <td class='title'> <img src='~/img/logo.png' style='width:100%; max-width:300px;' /> </td> <td> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id):@Html.Raw(Model.id) <br>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.module):@Html.Raw(Model.module) <br>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.explanation):@Html.Raw(Model.explanation) </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> <tr class='information '> <td colspan='2 '> <table> <tr> <td> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.situation):@Html.Raw(Model.situation) <br>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.end_date):@Html.Raw(Model.end_date) </td> <td> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> <tr class='heading '> <td> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.personels_notes) </td> <td></td> </tr> <tr class='item'> <td> @Html.Raw(Model.personels_notes) </td> </tr> <tr class='total '> <td></td> <td> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.personel):@Html.Raw(Model.personel) </td> </tr> </table> </div> </body> </html>";
            return (pageHtmlModel.HtmlCode);
        }
```

This is My Index Page For Open The Other Dynamic Model Pages

```
//This is catching object id for entity object
 
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', '#pdf', function () {
            if (!($(this).closest('tr').hasClass('selected'))) {
                table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');
            }
            obj = {}
            obj.id = $('tr.selected td').eq(0).html();
            window.location = "/Home/PDF/" + obj.id;            
            if ($(this).closest('tr').hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('selected');
            }

        })
```

Controller

```
        public IActionResult PDF(int id)
        {
             var result = new EntityDataAccess.DataObject();
             result.data = EntityDataAccess.OneObject(new Entity() { id = id });
             return View(EntityDataAccess.html(), result.data[0]);
        }
```

View => I just want to write this and see my all html page

```
@model myProject.Models.PageHtmlModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "PDF";
    Layout = null;
}
```

thanks for helping from now

Comment: Is there anything else that I can help you with?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use  `@Html.Raw()` `HTML` helpers to bind your `dynamic` `HTML` on your view. Here is the example for you.

***Controller Action:***

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult BindDynamicToHtml()
{
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var convertedHtmlBody = "";
    sb.Append("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    sb.Append("<html>");
    sb.Append("<head>");
    sb.Append("</head>");

    sb.Append("<body>");
    sb.Append("<p>Dear Coder,</p>");
    sb.Append("<p>Please check the following answer. This is how you can generate dynamic HTML to View</p>");
    sb.Append("<div style='max - height:500px; overflow: auto; width: 100 %; border - spacing: 0; '>");
    sb.Append("<style> table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; } th{ padding:2px; } </style>");
    sb.Append("<table style='width:20%;'>");
    sb.Append("<tr>");
    sb.Append("<th style='color:red;text-align:left;'>Test Bindings</th>");
    sb.Append("<th style='text-align:right'>40</th>");
    sb.Append("</tr>");
    sb.Append("</table>");
    sb.Append("<br />");
    sb.Append("<table style='width:20%;text-align:center;'>");
    sb.Append("<tr style='color:red;'>");
    sb.Append("<th style='text-align:center'>Name</th>");
    sb.Append("<th style='text-align:center'>Violations</th>");
    sb.Append("<th style='text-align:center'>Details</th>");
    sb.Append("</tr>");
    sb.Append("</table>");
    sb.Append("</div>");
    sb.Append("<hr/>");
    sb.Append("<p><strong style='color: red'>Note:</strong> For more details please check details: <a href='https://stackoverflow.com/users/9663070/md-farid-uddin-kiron'>Details</a></p>");
    sb.Append("</body>");
    sb.Append("</html>");
    convertedHtmlBody = sb.ToString();

    ViewBag.bindToHtmlInView = convertedHtmlBody;
    return View(); ;
}
```

***View:***

```cs
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "BindDynamicToHtml";
}

@Html.Raw(ViewBag.bindToHtmlInView)
```

***Output:***

[image]

> ***Note:*** If you would like to learn more about power of HTML helper you could refer to our [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) and [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0#built-in-aspnet-core-tag-helpers)

Hope it would help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: it worked but I can't access the links in the file. Normally If I use razor syntax I can see.

Comment: Finally you get back man, Okay I got your point, for the clarity of this question, I have shown you how can you achive this. So if you post new question with this concern that would be nice so that I can also guide you on this do that our two context remain seperate. Hope you got my point. Link also can be accessable in that case need to set some extra way around.